# Html Chat limit not found , also the scroll down ,

Tags: php

I got this code

```
  if  ($row['Sender'] == Admin ) {
        echo  '<div class="mesgs">              </div>';
        echo  '<div class="msg_history">              </div>';

  echo  '<div class="incoming_msg">            </div>';
  echo  '<div class="incoming_msg_img"><img src="https://ptetutorials.com/images/user-profile.png" alt="sunil">             </div>';
  echo  '<div class="received_msg">              </div>';
  echo  '<div class="received_withd_msg">              </div>';
  echo "<p>" . $row["message"] . "</p>";
  echo "<span class='time_date'>" . $row["dating"] . "</span>";
 } else {
echo  '<div class="mesgs">              </div>';
        echo  '<div class="msg_history">              </div>';
          echo  '<div class="outgoing_msg">             </div>';
          echo  '<div class="sent_msg">              </div>';
  echo "<p>" . $row["message"] . "</p>";
  echo "<span class='time_date'>" . $row["dating"] . "</span>";
```

It works fine , i'm supposed to get this [image]

But i get this, [image: what i get]
Like it's not in the chat , it gets out of the page , but i want a scroll down to check all the chat in the same size

the original code

```
<div class="mesgs">
      <div class="msg_history">
        <div class="incoming_msg">
          <div class="incoming_msg_img"> <img src="https://ptetutorials.com/images/user-profile.png" alt="sunil"> </div>
          <div class="received_msg">
            <div class="received_withd_msg">
              <p>Test which is a new approach to have all
                solutions</p>
              <span class="time_date"> 11:01 AM    |    June 9</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="outgoing_msg">
          <div class="sent_msg">
            <p>Test which is a new approach to have all
              solutions</p>
            <span class="time_date"> 11:01 AM    |    June 9</span> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="incoming_msg">
          <div class="incoming_msg_img"> <img src="https://ptetutorials.com/images/user-profile.png" alt="sunil"> </div>
          <div class="received_msg">
            <div class="received_withd_msg">
              <p>Test, which is a new approach to have</p>
              <span class="time_date"> 11:01 AM    |    Yesterday</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="outgoing_msg">
          <div class="sent_msg">
            <p>Apollo University, Delhi, India Test</p>
            <span class="time_date"> 11:01 AM    |    Today</span> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="incoming_msg">
          <div class="incoming_msg_img"> <img src="https://ptetutorials.com/images/user-profile.png" alt="sunil"> </div>
          <div class="received_msg">
            <div class="received_withd_msg">
              <p>We work directly with our designers and suppliers,
                and sell direct to you, which means quality, exclusive
                products, at a price anyone can afford.</p>
              <span class="time_date"> 11:01 AM    |    Today</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: And what have you tried to debug this? Looks like a CSS problem to me. PHP should not be related, or is the generated markup already not the one you'd expected?

Comment: i tried to debug it like in the ss , it was fine when i run it without php echo , but after i did echo and modifications it became like this , check both screenshots

Comment: So, you already had a version that is running properly? Then you should check what you've changed and undo these changes

Comment: Like i was checking for hours what i have changed , but could not find the difference between the original and the my version